# questions about a theorem regarding the limit of a composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Here is a theorem from my analysis textbook: Let $(a, b)$ be a (possibly infinite) interval and let $u$ equal  $a^+$ or $b^-$ .
If $g$ is defined on $(a, b)$ and $\lim_{x\to u }g(x) = L$, $f$ is defined on an interval containing
$L$ and the image of $g$, and $f$ is continuous at $L$, then
$\lim f (g ( x)) = f ( L)$.

This theorem appears to only cover the case of right and left hand limits. Am I correct in believing that theorem can be extended to say: "Let $(a, b)$ be a (possibly infinite) interval and let $u$ equal  $a^+$ or $b^-$ **or a point** $c$ **contained in** $(a,b)$.

Also,  the theorem requires that "$f$ is defined on an interval containing
$L$ and the image of $g$." I think we can actually weaken this hypothesis. All we actually need to say is the following: let "$f$ is defined on an interval containing
$L$" **and let this interval also be a subset of the image of** $g$." I don't think it is necesary to have $f$ defined on the entire image of $g$, we only need $f$ to be defined on some interval that is a subset of the image of $g$ and contains $L$. Do you agree?

Lastly, I am having trouble building intuition on why we need $f$ to be continuous at $L$. Can you give an intuitive(ideally visual) explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first intuition is broadly correct, and it's a consequence of the original theorem since if $c \in (a, b)$ then you can just apply the theorem on the interval $(a, c)$ or $(c, b)$ instead.

Your second thought is not actually describing a weaker condition for the theorem, since you require that $L$ be within the range of $g$ and the original theorem does not. However, with some adjustment you can again prove things as a corollary - if $L$ is not on the boundary of $f$, you should be able to define a subinterval $(a', b')$ such that the image $g((a', b'))$ is contained in some arbitrarily small neighbourhood of $L$ on which $f$ is defined, and where either $u = a'^+$ or $u = b'^-$ so that the theorem applies.

As for requiring $f$ be continuous, the problem is the same as any continuity problem - if $f(L) \neq \lim_{x \rightarrow L} f(x)$, then it doesn't matter how $x$ approaches $L$ you'll still get the wrong answer. For example, let $f(x) = 0$ everywhere except $f(0) = 1$. Then let $g(x)$ be defined so that $g(x) \neq 0$ when $x \in (a, b)$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow u} g(x) = 0$. So then for any $x \in (a, b)$, you'll have $f(g(x)) = 0$, and hence $\lim_{x \rightarrow u} f(g(x)) = 0 \neq f(0) = 1$.

Comment: you say "if $c∈(a,b)$ then you can just apply the theorem on the interval $(a,c)$ or $(c,b)$ instead." but this is not a helpful consequence of the theorem because it still does not say anything about the general limit $\lim_{x \to c} f (g ( x))$.  I may find that $\lim_{x\to c^+ }g(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to c^- }g(x) = L_2$. but this says nothing about $\lim_{x \to c} f (g ( x))$ as there is no distinction being made between the case where $L=L_2$ and $ L \ not = L_2 $. I still think that we can just simply make the theorem more general by adding: **or a point** $c$ **contained in** $(a,b)$.

Comment: "Your second thought is not actually describing a weaker condition for the theorem, since you require that $L$ be within the domain of $g$ and the original theorem does not." I do not agree with this either. no where do I require that $L$ be within the domain of $g$. I only require that $L$ be in the image of $g$, more specifically I say: "$f$ is defined on an interval containing 
$L$" **and let this interval also be a subset of the image of** $g$."

Comment: If the interval contains $L$ and it is also a subset of the image of $g$, then by definition $L$ must be in the image of $g$, no?

Comment: yes. it must be in the image of g, but you wrote domain.

Comment: My mistake, I meant image. The original theorem does not require that $L$ is in the image of $g$ though, which is the point.

Comment: but do you agree that f need not be defined on the entire image of g. f need not even be defined on all of the set $g((a,b))$. I think that f need only be defined on some open interval subset of $g((a,b))$ that also contains L.

Comment: I agree that if $f$ is defined on an appropriate sub-interval, then yes the theorem also applies. But that's fine, since as I said you can prove your version from the more restrictive one. This is quite common - you take a restrictive but easy to prove theorem, and use it to prove a more general version that would be harder to prove directly.